# retrieving only part of the record in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database which contains some topics each with a title and some description. In the title page, I have to display all the titles and a few lines of description for that topic. When a user clicks on one topic then he is taken to a page where he can find the entire description. Exactly like stackoverflow site, where description of each question is displayed in short.

I was wondering is there a way we can retrieve such short description from the database directly or should the front end parse the retrieved record and truncate it accordingly?  Is there a way to query for a short version of the record from the database directly. I am using MySql as my database and php to display web pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the answer is found in this post:
[SQL Server substring breaking on words, not characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722418/sql-server-substring-breaking-on-words-not-characters)

You wouldn't want to just limit by a string length, since then you might cut off a word right in the middle.  Instead, you would want to set your max length and then move back to the place where there is a space.

Another option would be to run this once and then update a field in the table that stores the truncated text.  That way you could limit your extra SQL calls and yet still have the nicely-formatted summary text.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`title`, 0, 100) FROM `topics`
```

Comment: Doing this, though, would cause you to cut off words right in the middle.  Unless you are OK with showing half a word, you should probably go further than this.

Comment: having complete words is better i think.

Answer (score 2):

**Best solution:**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('your string', ' ', 10);
```

this will return your string upto 10 spaces.

***Note:*** SUBSTRING cause you to cut off words right in the middle as suggested by @BiggsTRC

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Answer (score 1):

```
  select LEFT (description, CHARINDEX(' ', description, 50) ) from topics
```

this seems to address my problem correctly... any way thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a chunk of the text from a text field?

Like `select left(LongTextField,200) from myTable`

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the value you get back with a cast like this:
select title, cast(description as varchar(300)) from table

or you could store a less abrasive truncated description as a smallDescription or whatever in the table as well(then make your frontend let you mark it and it dissects it for you^^).